# Copy folder and its subfolders from puppet master to agent

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I'm trying to copy folder `/vagrant/scripts`  and its sub-folders located on puppet master into the agent. I use the following config in the `init.pp`:

```
file {
'/home/vagrant/scripts':
  ensure => 'file',
  source => 'puppet:///modules/ycsb/scripts',
  path => '/home/vagrant/YCSB/scripts',
  owner => 'vagrant',
  group => 'vagrant',
  mode  => '0744', # Use 0700 if it is sensitive
}
```

When I check the agent I can see `/scripts`  folder but without its sub-folders. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found out the problem. First, instead of 'file' use 'directory' at  *ensure* parameter . Second, make the copy process recursive to include all sub-folders.

```
file { 
 '/home/vagrant/scripts':
  ensure => 'directory',
  source => 'puppet:///modules/ycsb/scripts',
  recurse => 'remote',
  path => '/home/vagrant/YCSB/scripts',
  owner => 'vagrant',
  group => 'vagrant',
  mode  => '0744', # Use 0700 if it is sensitive
}
```